# set UITableViewCell height programmatically after getting json data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm trying to adjust height of UITableViewCell based on content after getting JSON data.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

I've added like that but UITableViewCell height cannot be increased based on content. Please help me how to solve.

```
- (void) getAllocatedJobs {
    _allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [SVProgressHUD show];
    dispatch_queue_t getInit = dispatch_queue_create("getinit",NULL);
    dispatch_async(getInit, ^{
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [commClass getJobs:strDriverId paramJobType:@""];
        NSNumber *status = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"Success"];
        NSString *message = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"Message"];
        NSArray *dataArray = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"lstJob"];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if([status intValue] == 1) {
                for(int i=0; i<[dataArray count]; i++) {
                    NSDictionary *JobData = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
                [_allocatedTable reloadData];

            } else {
                [commClass showAlert:APP_NAME alertMessage:message];
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`  then don't return it in  `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.Do it in `viewDidload` like,

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and autolayout is mandatory for `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` so make sure that you have set proper constraints. and reload table data when you get all json data successfully if needed.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate the height based on the content in this method:-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```